creating a looped stacked barplot with ggplot in R
I am trying to create a stacked barplot with ggplot in R. I have the following dataframe:



Sample
Date
Organism
Antibiotic
Resistance




1
01/01/2020
E Coli
Amoxicillin
S


1
01/01/2020
E Coli
Gentamicin
S


1
01/01/2020
E Coli
Cefalexin
R


2
01/01/2020
S aureus
Amoxicillin
S


2
01/01/2020
S aureus
Gentamicin
S


2
01/01/2020
S aureus
Cefalexin
R


3
01/01/2020
E Coli
Amoxicillin
S


3
01/01/2020
E Coli
Gentamicin
S


3
01/01/2020
E Coli
Cefalexin
S


4
02/01/2020
S aureus
Amoxicillin
S


4
02/01/2020
S aureus
Gentamicin
S


4
02/01/2020
S aureus
Cefalexin
R


5
02/01/2020
E coli
Amoxicillin
R


5
02/01/2020
E coli
Gentamicin
S


5
02/01/2020
E coli
Cefalexin
R


6
03/01/2020
E coli
Amoxicillin
R


6
03/01/2020
E coli
Gentamicin
R


6
03/01/2020
E coli
Cefalexin
S


7
04/01/2020
E coli
Amoxicillin
S


7
04/01/2020
E coli
Gentamicin
S


7
04/01/2020
E coli
Cefalexin
S


8
04/01/2020
S aureus
Amoxicillin
S


8
04/01/2020
S aureus
Gentamicin
S


8
04/01/2020
S aureus
Cefalexin
S


9
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Amoxicillin
S


9
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Gentamicin
S


9
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Cefalexin
S


10
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Amoxicillin
R


10
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Gentamicin
R


10
05/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Cefalexin
R


11
05/01/2020
E coli
Amoxicillin
S


11
05/01/2020
E coli
Gentamicin
S


11
05/01/2020
E coli
Cefalexin
S


12
06/01/2020
S aureus
Amoxicillin
S


12
06/01/2020
S aureus
Gentamicin
S


12
06/01/2020
S aureus
Cefalexin
S


13
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Amoxicillin
S


13
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Gentamicin
S


13
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Cefalexin
S


14
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Amoxicillin
R


14
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Gentamicin
R


14
06/01/2020
Kleb pneumo
Cefalexin
R



I would like to create a stacked bar charts with ggplot by each Organism and each antibiotic with Date along the x-axis. I would like to do this for 1) by sample counts per day and 2) by percent of samples per day.  Dates have already been converted to the date format using the as.Date function. I imagine it may be using a for loop including the following code, which currently just gives me a stacked percentage chart for Resistance and not by Organism and Antibiotic?
ggplot(sens_df, aes(fill=Resistance, , x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="count") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") 

Thank you very much for your help!

Study help("facet_grid").

Use facet_wrap() Antibiotic to create two plots, then put those together with patchwork (p1/p2)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(sens_df, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs (y = "percent") +
  facet_wrap(~Antibiotic, scales = "free_y")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
p2 <- ggplot(sens_df, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number) +
  labs (y = "count") +
  facet_wrap(~Antibiotic, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p1 / p2 


You can achieve this like Roland and Michiel say with facet_wrap. The answer Michiel provides is good, and if you'd like such a plot for every organism you could do something like this:
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)    

organisms <- unique(sens_df$Organism)
    
    for(i in organisms){
        
        sens_selection = filter(sens_df, 
                                Organism == i)
      
    p1 <- ggplot(sens_selection, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
      geom_bar(position="fill") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
      labs (y = "percent") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", 
                   date_labels =  "%d-%m") +
      facet_wrap(~Antibiotic, scales = "free_y")+
      theme(legend.position = "none")
    
    p2 <- ggplot(sens_selection, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
      geom_bar(position="stack") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number) +
      labs (y = "count") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", 
                   date_labels =  "%d-%m") +
      facet_wrap(~Antibiotic, scales = "free_y") +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
    
     p3 <- p1 / p2 +
      plot_annotation(title = paste0(i))
     
     print(p3)
    }

If you wanted an individual plot for each antibiotic-organism combination then you could use a nested for loop or lapply. With a for loop you could achieve it by:
    organisms <- unique(sens_df$Organism)
    antibiotics <- unique(sens_df$Antibiotic)
    
    for(i in organisms){
      for(j in antibiotics){
    
    sens_selection = filter(sens_df, 
                            Organism == i,
                            Antibiotic == j)
    
    p1 <- ggplot(sens_selection, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
      geom_bar(position="fill") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
      labs (y = "percent") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", 
                   date_labels =  "%d-%m") +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
    
    p2 <- ggplot(sens_selection, aes(fill=Resistance, x=Date)) + 
      geom_bar(position="stack") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number) +
      labs (y = "count") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", 
                   date_labels =  "%d-%m") +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
    
    p3 <- p1 / p2 +
      plot_annotation(title = paste0(i, "-", j ))
    
    print(p3)
  }
}

